# Telerik RadDateTimePicker to display Time along with Date in Date control

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have the following code

```
<telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="dtpDate" runat="server" EnableTyping="false"></telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
```

Date is coming properly but time is not visible in the date control. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="dtpDate" runat="server" EnableTyping="false">
<TimeView Interval="00:15:00"></TimeView>
</telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
```

You can try adding the `TimeView` tag within the RadDateTimePicker and that should give you the time part.

More explanations can be found in [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/calendar/raddatepicker,-radtimepicker,-raddatetimepicker-and-radmonthyearpicker/configuring-the-embedded-time-view).

Update:
To see the time part in the input textbox, you can specify the date time format string in the mark up, e.g.

```
DateInput-DateFormat="dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
```

Comment: TimeView is displaying Time icon but the selected Time selected is not visible in the datetime picker textbox associated to it.

Comment: Time not working when  I set DateInput DateFormat.  Only date is displayed.

Comment: @CPK_2011 You need to provide the aspx markup code. It's fine from my end. One thing you can try yourself is just add this RadDateTimePicker control onto a blank page. Apply your custom date format and see how it renders.